# Save output of cell in Jupyter where loop

Tags: python, file

I want to save the output of a given cell in Jupyter in a file. This cell is made of a `for` loop where each iteration makes an output.

What I've tried so far :

```
%%capture cap --no-stderr
```

before the loop, and then :

```
with open(mylist[index]+'.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(cap.stdout)
```

at the very end of the loop (last instruction of the loop). However, I get an error :

> name 'cap' is not defined

I am a bit confused about how to proceed...

Thanks